# How to create different mousedown callbacks dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousedown

I am trying to create multiple divs each with a mousedown callback.

But that callback function should not be common for all the divs , it should function differently depending upon the div clicked.

Here is the code I am using the generate the divs and setting the callbacks.

```
    //some number
    var num=4;

    for(var z = 0 ; z < num ;z++)
    {
        //create a div with id 'z'
        $("<div/>",{id:z}).appendTo("#empty");

        //displaying the id on the screen 
        $("#"+z).text(z);   

        console.log("button "+z+" created");

        //Callback function , which is not working as I want it to. See the bottom section for more details
        $("#"+z).mousedown(function(){
            console.log("Button "+z+" clicked !");
        });
    }
```

The above code runs as follows...

[image: output]

**On clicking anyone of the divs the message "Button 4 clicked!" is generated in the console.**

What should be done in order to achieve what I was aiming for ?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkvudakr/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use a class for the buttons and create a callback for the item.

```
var num=4;

for(var z = 0 ; z < num ;z++)
{
    //create a div with id 'z'
    $("<div/>",{id:z,class:'btn'}).appendTo("#empty");

    //displaying the id on the screen 
    $("#"+z).text(z);   

    console.log("button "+z+" created");
}

$(".btn").mousedown(function(){
    var z = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log("Button "+z+" clicked !");
});
```

Comment: If your going to use classes, why still give the divs ids, especially ids as generic as 0-3?

Comment: Also since the buttons are being created dynamically, it might be better to use `.on('mousedown'...`.

Comment: I think giving ids and classes are fine for this situation as they will allow to easily trace back the index of the div called.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of your button, try modifying your code as:

```js
var num = 4;
var btn;

for (var z = 0; z < num; z++) {
  btn = $("<div>", {
    id: z,
    text: z
  }).appendTo("#empty");

  btn.on('click', function() {
    alert("Button " + $(this).text() + " clicked !");
  });
}
```

```css
#empty div {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='empty'></div>
```

Using single click handler:

```js
$(function() {
  var num = 4;
  var btn;
  var empty = $("#empty");

  empty.on('click', 'div.btn', function() {
    alert("Button " + $(this).text() + " clicked !");
  });

  for (var z = 0; z < num; z++) {
    btn = $("<div>", {
      'id': z,
      'text': z,
      'class': 'btn'
    });
    empty.append(btn);
  }
});
```

```css
div.btn {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='empty'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your elements a class. Then use the index of the clicked element within that class to know which one was click and act on that:

```js
    //some number
    var num=4;

    for(var z = 0 ; z < num ;z++)
    {
       $('#divHolder').append('<div class="mydivs"></div>');
    }




$('body').on('mousedown', '.mydivs', function() {
  
  // get the index of the clicked div
  var curDiv = $('.mydivs').index(this);
  
  // call a function and pass it this index
  doStuff(curDiv);
});


function doStuff(clickedDiv){
  // the index that was passed in will tell you what
  // div was clicked do something with that
  $('#show').html( 'you clickded div:' + clickedDiv);
};
```

```css
.mydivs{
  background-color:#cccccc;
  margin-top:15px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show"></div>
<div id="divHolder"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this problem is to handle the event outside of the for loop.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
//some number
var num=4;

for(var z = 0 ; z < num ;z++)
{
  //create a div with id 'z'
  $("<div/>",{id:z}).appendTo("#empty");

  //displaying the id on the screen 
  $("#"+z).text(z);   

  console.log("button "+z+" created");
}

//Callback function taken out of the for loop and added event delegation since it is a dynamically added element
$(document).on('click', 'div div', function(){
  console.log("Button "+ $(this).attr('id') +" clicked !");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="empty"></div>
```